# What are the best WBS and Gantt chart tool working cross platform?

Tags: software-recommendation, software

I am searching for the good tools for creating Work Breakdown Structure and Gantt Chart that work cross platform because other people in my team use `Window`. So, this forces me to find cross platform tools.

What have found so far are :

[OpenProj](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openproj/) : I have used it. The behavior is so quirky that why I gave up.

[GanttProject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/index.php) : Cool tool! It can be used to create Gantt along with PERT chart. However, it cannot generate WBS chart.

I have searched a lot and I didn't find the one that I love.

Could you please share your great tools that you are using along with advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

http://teamgantt.com … used by Oracle, Twitter, Sony. You will have to call whether their features are close enough to a WBS to be acceptable.
Allows for CSV file import (a file format exported by MS Project).